# Scala iterators are confusing

Tags: scala, iterator, iteration

[image: Click here to see the problem statement image]

I tried very hard to understand why iterators are behaving like that. I mean after performing once

```
result = lines.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toInt)
```

the iterator buffer is over written with all elemnets except the last element.

I mean if I have 5 elements in my input text file after giving 5 times

```
result = lines.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toInt)
```

my iterator is becoming empty.

Any help is much appreciated.... Thanks in advance

Comment: @victor-moroz I see now you were demonstrating the gotcha. So the answer is, "Yes, iterators are very confusing when you misuse them." We have notions like "fail-fast" to say, "If I misuse you, please blow up in a way I can debug easily."

Answer (score 5):

The doc is very clear that you must discard an iterator after invoking any method except next and hasNext.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Iterator

Answer (score 0):

som-snytt is right here, but didn't explain what exactly was going on.

When you transform an iterator, you need to save the result of the transformation and only use that.  In particular, calling `filter` on an iterator internally buffers it, which calls `next` on the original iterator and saves it in a `head` variable.  If you call `next` on the buffered thing, you get 4.  If you call `next` on the original iterator, you get 8: your first element is gone.  If you'd instead written:

```
var result = lines.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toInt)
var result = result.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toInt)
var result = result.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toInt)
```

You could repeat the last line as many times as you want without the iterator becoming empty, because you're always operating on the transformed iterator.

EDIT: to address the buffering comment -- here's the code for `Iterator.filter`:

```
def filter(p: A => Boolean): Iterator[A] = new AbstractIterator[A] {
  private var hd: A = _
  private var hdDefined: Boolean = false

  def hasNext: Boolean = hdDefined || {
    do {
      if (!self.hasNext) return false
      hd = self.next()
    } while (!p(hd))
    hdDefined = true
    true
  }

  def next() = if (hasNext) { hdDefined = false; hd } else empty.next()
}
```

The `hd` and `hdDefined` variables perform exactly the same buffering that is used in `Iterator.buffered`.

Comment: `.filter` doesn't buffer anything when you call it on iterator, but when you call `hasNext` on `.filter` it will destroy some (all) elements from original iterator. Which happens if you do it in REPL since REPL calls `hasNext`. I had an answer explaining how it actually works, but such explanation is irrelevant. Just don't do it.

Comment: `Iterator.filter` code directly contradicts your statement though. Calling `.filter` simply returns a new object, buffering happens in `hasNext` and `next`.

Comment: Not sure what the code snippet means to demonstrate, but it's worth saying that particular methods on particular iterators may/may not be destructive, but those are implementation details, and you must never rely on them.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.  I tried to provide an implementation detail to explain why you can't rely on the original, but I probably just misdirected attention from the important point (don't reuse base iterators after transformations).  Sorry!